# Robot framework get result

Tags: return, output, robotframework

I trying to use the library SapGuiLibrary and want to get some values from SAP.

In my test case I have:

```
SapGuiLibrary.Get Row Count    wnd[0]/shellcont[1]/shell
```

But how to I output the value to log or a file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the keyword returns the value, you can [save it to a variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-values-from-keywords). You can then log the variable.

```
${result}=    SapGuiLibrary.Get Row Count  wnd[0]/shellcont[1]/shell
log to console  ${result}
```